# PostgreSQL function to recort uint in smallint

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, unsigned-integer

I want to store a unsigned int (0 to 65535) into a smallint.

I'd expect something like:

```
CAST(($1 - 32768) AS smallint)
```

My table has a column

```
version smallint NOT NULL
```

How can I do to `INSERT INTO mytable SET(1);` and it will record -32767
and when I `SELECT version from myTable;` it will return 1 ?

Comment: smallint should be able to take values -32768 to +32767 per PostgreSQL documentation.. What exactly does your table look like and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to give uint in the query and store uint in smallint

Comment: Why don't you just use an `integer` and create a check constraint that limits the values? It depends on the rest of the columns in your table but I highly doubt that you would see a big difference in storage size and performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view on top of your table, which selects `(version + 32768) as version` (This column of the view will be of type int. You can add an explicit cast too). Then you should query this view instead of the original table to get values between 0-65535.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW myTableView AS SELECT col1, col2, (version::int + 32768) as version FROM myTable;
```

Now, `SELECT version FROM myTableView` will return values between 0 and 65535.

For INSERTs, you can create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger for myTableView, which inserts (version - 32768)::smallint into myTable. This should be easy enough, but I can't test it right now so I don't give a sample.